# AIX equivalent of Solaris' iostat -E

Tags: aix, disk, scsi

On Solaris you can use the command `iostat -En` to view "disk error statistics" as counted by the kernel since the last reboot, where the `-n` option causes iostat to show "nice" device names.

I'm looking for a way to similar statistics on AIX.

Bonus question:  How to get this kind of information out of Linux?  smartctl?  Parse syslog?

Comment: Maybe better to ask in [sf].

Comment: @fedorqui Why would a question about AIX get better answers in Server Fault than in U&L?

Comment: Because sys admins are likely to know about it.

Comment: This Q is perfectly on-topic for this site. You could've asked it there as well. Many of the SE sites overlap, it's the OP's prerogative where to ask a Q when it does.

Comment: @slm OK. I didn't mean this is off-topic here, just that it is more likely to have people knowing it among system administrators...

Comment: @fedorqui - it's difficult to say which site has more ppl w/ that skill. This site has ~188 Q's tagged as AIX while SF has only ~44.

Comment: @slm well, it really depends... [aix] + "disk" shows 17 matches here, while 45 there. Whatever, just looking for a way for the OP to get an answer, the off-topic issue is the less important aspect to me :)

Comment: @fedorqui - yes yes it depends, that's why I said it's up to the OP. Didn't want to get into a splitting hairs, was merely showing "one way" to "break it down" 8-). This Q could surely be rephrased and asked on both sites IMO, BTW.

Comment: @slm Nice! And I just learnt the idiom "splitting hairs", thanks :)

Comment: Try the commands mentioned in the [Rosetta Stone](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html). I don't have AIX, but from the [man page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/iostat.htm?lang=en), doesn't `iostat -b` show what you want?

Comment: @gilles The Rosetta stone doesn't help. (Geez this is old, sorely lacking some updates)  It gives some broad approximate equivalents, but for a specific detail such as this it doesn't have the answer.  As per the referred man page the -b option produces disk utilization statistics, I am looking for IO / SCSI error statistics.

Comment: Can you include an example of the output you're seeing on Solaris? Your description and your comments seem at odds (disk errors vs IO/SCSI errors).  I think on AIX -b does do what you want, but if you give an example ...